# How is onchange and addEventListener different?

Tags: javascript, slider, dom-events

I am using a third-party slider library (unknown which) and I need it to update the text value whenever the slider is dragged to a new position. The current code, which works,  looks like this:

```
opacitySlider = new Slider(document.getElementById("opacitySlider"), document.getElementById("opacity"));
opacitySlider.setMinimum(0);
opacitySlider.setMaximum(100);
opacitySlider.setUnitIncrement(2);
alert("setting onchange event");
opacitySlider.onchange = function()  {
  document.getElementById("opacityDisplay").textContent = opacitySlider.getValue() + "%";
};
alert("onchange event set");
opacitySlider.onchange();

<div style="display: table">
  <div style="display: table-cell; width: 15%">
    <span id=" opacityDisplay"></span>
  </div>
  <div style="display: table-cell">
    <div id="opacitySlider" class="slider">
      <input class="slider-input">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Both alerts fired off and both the slider and the text value are successfully rendered. However, when I replace `onchange = function()  {...};` with `addEventListener("change", function() {...});`, only the first alert is fired, and the slider is rendered but not the text value.

```
alert("setting onchange event");
opacitySlider.addEventListener("change", function()  {
  document.getElementById("opacityDisplay").textContent = opacitySlider.getValue() + "%";
});
alert("onchange event set");
```

I don't understand why this is happening. What are the possible reasons for this behaviour? How can I use `addEventListener` instead of `onchange`?

Using event listeners is preferred to maintain consistency with the rest of my application which uses event listeners too. This is the only event listener I have issues with. This application will be deployed on Internet Explorer 11.212.10586.0.

Comment: Calling `opacitySlider.onchange();` like that is bad (doesn’t trigger an event or anything); define a function, use it with `addEventListener`, then call it separately. Also, please show a real example; `.text content` isn’t even syntactically valid.

Comment: @Ryan sorry, autocorrect, will edit it. And this is the actual example.

Comment: If the second alert doesn't display that implies an error occured when trying to call `.addEventListener()` - any errors shown in the browser console? Is the first line of your first codeblock supposed to be `opacitySlider = ...`? If that variable is not a reference to a DOM element then you can't call `addEventListener()` on it.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes it's supposed to be `opacitySlider`, I'm typing on phone so there may be autocorrect that I've not caught. I'm not sure if it's a DOM element or not. So I can't call `addEventListener` if it's not DOM? Isn't it the same as any `onchange` or similar?

Comment: Which slider library are you using?

Comment: @Ryan I've no idea. Within the application code and the slider library, the only thing I have is a version number but no information on the author etc. I'm conducting remediation on this legacy application, and the project that developed this has no documentation...

Comment: Ha, sorry, missed the first words of your question. Well, you’re going to have to go into it and look at how it works. It sounds like this isn’t actually the DOM 0 `onchange`, though, and is just something the library uses with the same name, in which case you don’t need to change it for consistency.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially they are the same, but you can only bind one event to the `onchange` property because it replaces the existing event, whereas `addEventListener` can bind multiple change events, or other events.

There is a browser compatibility difference as well, `addEventListener` does not work with older IE versions <=IE8 I believe.

Comment: I've no compatibility issue. The application will only be deployed on one configuration and my other event listeners work perfectly. It's just this one.